# Cygwin terminal, mintty missing

Tags: cygwin, mintty

I have Cygwin terminal and am trying to set it up on my PC. I run windows 8 and when I try to open Cygwin terminal I receive attached pop up, "searching for mintty, cannot locate". If anyone knows how to fix respond. ![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a Google search?

I just did, and various things pointing to Windows8 came up.